# Python : What's wrong with the dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

My Code :

```
dict( (k,v) if k in ['1','2','3','4'] else (k,None)  for k,v in {'1':'one','2':'two'}.items() )
```

Expected Output :

```
{'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3':None, '4':None}
```

Actual Output :

```
{'1': 'one', '2': 'two'}
```

Please help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `for` clause only contains 2 items, so your final dict is only going to have 2 items. The 4-item list is only used as a comparison, not as a source of values to use.

Answer (score 6):

```
if k in ['1','2','3','4']
```

is a condition, not an iteration (see the `if`).

You can write it as:

```
dict((k, {'1':'one','2':'two'}.get(k, None)) for k in ['1','2','3','4'])

# returns: {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': None, '4': None}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way.

Answer (score 4):

This would give the required result, as you need to traverse the list for 4 elements, and then assign respective values in the dictionary :

```
theDict = {'1':'one','2':'two'}
s = dict( (k,theDict[k]) if k in theDict else (k,None)  for k in ['1','2','3','4'] )
```

Answer (score 2):

u iterate over a dict with two keys, not a 4-element list

my code:

```
dict( (k, {'1':'one', '2':'two'}.get(k, None)) for k in ['1', '2','3', '4'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If my crystal ball wasn't broken, I would guess you want the other direction: iterate `k` over the list and check if it is in the dictionary.

In this case, you might find useful

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
testdict = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'}
res = dict((k, testdict.get(k, None)) for k in l)
```

This iterates over `l` and yields a `(k, testdict[k])` tuple if `k` is in the `testdict`.
If not, it yields `(k, None)` - exactly as you (supposedly!) want.